# Android Customized Toolbar causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm trying to implement a customized toolbar but I face this error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no  stack available

I have support library v4 & appcompat v7. I tried every thing but nothing works.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.customized_toolbar;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */

Toolbar mToolbar;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    mToolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

}

private void SetSupportActionBar(Toolbar mToolbar) {
}
```

}

```
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<include
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

toolbar_default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

the menu file is main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_reply"
       android:title="Reply"
 />

<item android:id="@+id/action_undo"
      android:title="Undo"

       />


</menu>
```

Styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
<style name="Theme"></style>
<style name="Theme.AppCompat"></style>
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"></style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"></style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

  </style>

</resources><br/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.customized_toolbar"
      android:versionCode="1"

      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Share your build.gradle file!

Comment: I think you are using old build tools. Update the SDK manager, In the latest ActionBarActivity is deprecated.

Comment: @LucasCrawford I don't know how to get this file.

Comment: Are you using eclipse or android studio

Comment: Where you have this error - on emu, or on phone. If on phone - can you give info about device? I'm asking about this, as I had this issue on some specific devices - it was Wiko devices, or some Samsungs with specific OS. Solution for this was little more complicated, as it required using proguard

Comment: @LucasCrawford android studio

Comment: @MateuszPryczkowski I tried it with different devices. Sony Xperia Z3 and Huawei Ascend Mate7.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 mToolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
```

to

```
 mToolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Make sure your MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
instead of ActionBarActivity

Change

```
SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

to

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar mToolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
     {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        menu.getItem(0);
        menu.getItem(1);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. it gives me this error:
at com.example.customized_toolbar.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:40)
the line is: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: can you please update your post with MainActivity.java till line 50?

Comment: @Hadis, I've updated my answer, please use above code and report back here

Comment: Make sure you type correctly the method names.
Also change access specifier of method onCreate to protected as above @Hadis

Comment: it gives me the same error.
the last line of error is:
     **Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available**

Comment: Change following lines of your manifest as follows `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme">`

Comment: does your gradle have following code ? `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`